# print all elements of a dictionary? Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I can't seem to figure out how to print all elements of a dictionary! I keep getting errors saying that it is not defined.

The file I am using (mood.txt):

```
happy, Jennifer Clause
happy, Jake Foster
sad, Jonathan Bower
mad, Penny
excited, Logan 
awkward, Mason Tyme
```

my code:

```
def theFile():
    moodFile = open("mood.txt")
    theMood = moodFile.readlines()
    moodFile.close()
    return(theMood)

def makeTheDict(myFile):
    moodDict = {}

    for lines in myFile:
        (mood, name) = lines.split(",")

        moodDict[mood] = name.strip()

    return(moodDict)


def printMood(mood, moodDict):

    if mood in moodDict:
        print("The people who are", mood, ":", moodDict[mood])


def allMoods(moodDict):

    #code I am having trouble with
    for moods in moodDict:
        print(mood, moodDict[moods])


def main():

    moodFile = theFile()

    moodDict = makeTheDict(moodFile)

    findMood = input("Which mood do you want to choose?: ")
    printMood(findMood, moodDict)

    allMoods(moodDict)
```

I am trying to print all the moods inside the function `allMoods()`. Whenever I remove mood from `print(mood, moodDict[moods])` , it prints out all the names fine, but when I insert the mood it says it is not defined.

I tried calling `printMood(mood, moodDict)` inside `allMoods()` but I couldn't get that to work either!

How do I print out everyones moods with their name? Can anyone help! Thanks!

Comment: You said `for moods in moodDict`, so `mood` isn't defined.  It should be `for mood in moodDict`.

Comment: Can you show us the result that you are expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had `moods` and `mood` in this routine. You need just one of them. `mood` seems best.

```py
def allMoods(moodDict):
    for mood in moodDict:
        print(mood, moodDict[mood])
```

With that change, everything works. It works now because you have defined `mood` in the `for` loop, where previously you were calling on `mood`, but had never defined or set it to anything.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand now :)